# Freezing of threads that doesn't allow to recognize a pattern

Tags: python, wxpython, python-imaging-library

I have a Python application that uses wxPython and some additional threads. One thread uses [`PIL.Image.open`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm). Under certain circumstances the application freezes so that you see an uncomplete GUI. I found out that it hangs at `PIL.Image.open`. When I put debug `print`s in the PIL module, I can see one time it hangs here, one time there ... -- which I can't understand. It seems totally unrelated.

Is there anything a thread can do in Python, that causes other threads to stop at actually unproblematic lines like `import string`? Or is wxPython able to give such influence?

Answer (score 3):

Long running tasks will freeze a GUI, like wxPython or Tkinter. Putting the long running process into a thread usually takes care of the issue though. I am guessing that you are doing something in your thread that communicates with wxPython in a non-thread-safe manner. If you are **not** using wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater or wx.PostEvent to communicate with wxPython from the thread, then that is the issue. You have to use one of those methods.

Otherwise we'll need a small runnable example to diagnose the issue.